# How can I handle these nested events?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem  with nested events

**consider this is html code:**

```
<button id="first">first button </button>

<button id="second">second button </button>
```

**and this is jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#first').click(function() {
    $('#second').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

});

when  the first button is clicked n times ... then click the first button one time .. the alert is shown n times.

i want to handle this:

to become when click on the first button n times ... then click in the first button one time .. the alert is shown **one** times

but without using `one()` Method

Comment: May i ask you why you are nesting click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `off()` to unbind event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first').click(function() {
        $('#second').off('click').click(function() {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
var isBind = false;
$('#first').click(function() {
   if(!isBind){
    $('#second').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
    isBind = true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flags (known as locks in the concept of Threading).

Something such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $('#first').click(function() {
        clicked = true;
    });
    $('#second').click(function() {
         if(clicked){
            alert('test');
            clicked = false;
         }
    });
});
```

As the second event is only used when `window.clicked` is true.

I know, this is ugly, but..It works and it's simple of understand. (and it support multiple event listeners, just remember to change the name of the attribute of the object `window`)

Comment: Note that you don't have to define it on window, you could just as well have just done `var clicked = false` and used it directly inside, thus removing the possibility of a global conflict.

Comment: @KevinB In some of my tests occurs errors related to the context of the function vs. the parent. In Python i know that this is mostly fine, but in Javascript i prefer to use some global variable to avoid problems with the recognition of the variable value.

Comment: @KevinB By the way, i've fixed thhe code according to your suggestion.